# Handling matrix multiplication in log space in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am implementing a Hidden Markov Model and thus am dealing with very small probabilities. I am handling the underflow by representing variables in log space (so x → log(x)) which has the side effect that multiplication is now replaced by addition and addition is handled via `numpy.logaddexp` or similar.

Is there an easy way to handle matrix multiplication in log space?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the best way I could come up with to do it.

```
from scipy.special import logsumexp
def log_space_product(A,B):
    Astack = np.stack([A]*A.shape[0]).transpose(2,1,0)
    Bstack = np.stack([B]*B.shape[1]).transpose(1,0,2)
    return logsumexp(Astack+Bstack, axis=0)
```

The inputs A and B are the logs of the matrices A<sub>0</sub> and B<sub>0</sub> you want to multiply, and the functions returns the log of A<sub>0</sub>B<sub>0</sub>. The idea is that the i,j spot in log(A<sub>0</sub>B<sub>0</sub>) is the log of the dot product of the ith row of A<sub>0</sub> and the jth column of B<sub>0</sub>. So it is the logsumexp of the ith row of A plus the jth column of B.

In the code, Astack is built so the i,j spot is a vector containing the ith row of A, and Bstack is built so the i,j spot is a vector containing the jth column of B. Thus Astack + Bstack is a 3D tensor whose i,j spot is the ith row of A plus the jth column of B. Taking logsumexp with axis = 0 then gives the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

Erik's response doesn't seem to work for some non-square matrices (e.g. n*m times m*r). Here is a version that takes that into account:

```py
def log_space_product(A,B):
    Astack = np.stack([A]*B.shape[1]).transpose(1,0,2)
    Bstack = np.stack([B]*A.shape[0]).transpose(0,2,1)
    return logsumexp(Astack+Bstack, axis=2)
```

where the i, j spot of A contains the i-th row of A and i, j spot of B contains the i-th column of B.

This happens because [A] * B.shape[1] is of shape (r, n, m) which is transposed into (n, r, m), and [B] * A.shape[0] is of shape (n, m, r) which is transposed into (n, r, m). We want their first two dimensions to be (n, r) because the result matrix needs to be of shape (n, r).

Took a while to figure out myself. Hope this helps anyone implementing a HMM!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the helpful answers here.

FWIW, here's a version of Andi's non-square matrix version that works if A and B have additional leading axes, as e.g. is the case if you want to apply this using `jax.lax.associative_scan`.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import logsumexp

# Log space matrix product via https://stackoverflow.com/a/74409968
# Equivalent of np.log (np.einsum('...ij,...jk->...ik', np.exp(A), np.exp(B)))
def log_matmul(A,B):
    assert A.ndim == B.ndim
    assert A.ndim >= 2
    assert A.shape[0:-2] == B.shape[0:-2]
    Astack = np.einsum ('k...ij->...ikj', np.stack([A]*B.shape[-1]))
    Bstack = np.einsum ('i...jk->...ikj', np.stack([B]*A.shape[-2]))
    return logsumexp(Astack+Bstack, axis=-1)
```

Test:

```
>>> A=np.arange(12).reshape((1,3,4))+1
>>> B=np.arange(20).reshape((1,4,5))+10
>>> A@B
array([[[200, 210, 220, 230, 240],
        [480, 506, 532, 558, 584],
        [760, 802, 844, 886, 928]]])
>>> np.exp(log_matmul(np.log(A),np.log(B)))
array([[[200., 210., 220., 230., 240.],
        [480., 506., 532., 558., 584.],
        [760., 802., 844., 886., 928.]]])
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/ihh/9ecb8bbbe4c8050aa39bc3e5f1cbe9b5) is a gist showing how to use this to implement the Forward algorithm for HMMs using `associative_scan`.