# Method of matrix multiplication between two numpy matrices of log2 elements

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, logarithm

I have two `numpy` matrices `a_log2` and `b_log2` of `log2` elements and I want to perform **matrix multiplication** between them.

```
a = np.array([[0.4, 0.4, 0.2],
          [0.1, 0.5, 0.4]])

b = np.array([[0.3, 0.7],
          [0.5, 0.5],
          [0.2, 0.8]])

a_log2 = np.log2(a)
b_log2 = np.log2(b)
```

I used to perform matrix multiplication of `e-based logarithms` using `scipy.special.logsumexp`. Here is the code I use (thanks to Erik Parkinson for his answer in this thread [Handling matrix multiplication in log space in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36467022/handling-matrix-multiplication-in-log-space-in-python)):

```
def log_space_product(A,B):
   Astack = np.stack([A]*A.shape[0]).transpose((2,1,0))
   Bstack = np.stack([B]*B.shape[1]).transpose((1,0,2))
   log_sum_exp = logsumexp(Astack+Bstack, axis=0)
   return log_sum_exp
```

Now, **I need your help in performing matrix multiplication between** `a_log2` and `b_log2` because `scipy.special.logsumexp` was not defined for `base-2 logarithms`.

**Note:**
I was firstly planning to convert the matrix elements into `natural logarithms` using `a_loge[i, j] = np.log(2**a_log2[i, j])` and `b_loge[i, j] = np.log(2**b_log2[i, j])`, and then using the aforementioned `log_space_product()` method to perform the matrix multiplication.

But I resisted myself doing that because the matrices I will eventually work with have `> 1000` rows and `> 20` columns. (*Don't get confused with the numbers of rows and the number of columns here. I do ensure that the matrix multiplication properties are maintained.*)

Answer (score 1):

Remember that *log<sub>2</sub>(x) = ln(x)/ln(2)*. We can rewrite that as *ln(x) = c log<sub>2</sub>(x)* with *c = ln(2)*.  So conversion to/from log spaces with a different base is literally one multiplication.

```
from scipy.special import logsumexp

def log_space_product(A, B, base=np.e):
    c = np.log(base)
    Astack = np.stack([A]*A.shape[0]).transpose(2,1,0)
    Bstack = np.stack([B]*B.shape[1]).transpose(1,0,2)
    return (1/c) * logsumexp(c*(Astack+Bstack), axis=0)
```

Comment: Thank you.  BTW shouldn't it be "c = np.log(2)" instead of "c=np.log(np.e)" since our target logarithm base is 2?

Comment: @MdMorshedAlam I wrote a generic function, where I think it makes the most sense to use the natural log as the default. In your case since you are working in a log space with base 2, you'd call `log_space_product(A, B, base=2)`.

Comment: Got you. Appreciate your help.